# Sphinx full text search example yii2

Tags: yii2

I wonder if there is any available step by step tutorial regarding the use of Sphinx component??? My task is to search the results of an ActiveDataProvider (content field which is text). I'm newbie of Yii2 framework (I have already searched the internet but with no luck)!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls make an example for me using this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-sphinx-query.html)